# Golang webserver local.rc on raspbian how to autostart?

Tags: linux, bash, go, raspbian, autostart

i can run this everywhere **on my shell**:

```
bash ~/Documents/myfolder/subfolder/service/autorun.sh
```

this is my autorun.sh this should start the builded go webservice:

`#!/bin/bash
cd ./bin/
sudo ./client-service`

**this works** if i run it on my shell.
**But** if i want to use it **in my rc.local** for autostart on raspbian with this code:

```
bash ~/Documents/myfolder/subfolder/service/autorun.sh
```

The bash script should start the go webserver.

```
~/Documents/myfolder/subfolder/service/bin/client-service
```

But it won't start

I hope someone can help me with this problem!
thx

Answer (score 0):

You are using the '~' character in your path. That means that the path is relativ to the home-directory of the user that is running the script. 
Calling the script as a user, everything works fine, but calling the script as root user, it will try to use */root/Documents/myfolder/sub...* as path and this will not work. Try to do run the script with an absolute path, or even better try to deploy your service on a more common place.

Comment: you mean /home/pi/Documents/... i thought i had tried this before...i will give it a try again

Comment: no does also not work. maybe i have to say that each python scripts works with absolute path to the same directory but go won't - > maybe go script specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i had to install a service within /etc/init.d -> now i works without any problems (with the same script & absolute path)